# pip, easy_install, and conda can't have issues with ssl certificate confirming

Tags: python, ssl

Hey I recently updated to osX 10.12.4 immediately after updating i began receiving errors when i would try to install python packages. Or in the case conda i couldn't create a new virtual enviroment. Conda is being used in the context of anaconda. Here are the command line responses i received.

Pip:

```
pip install tensorflow 

Collecting tensorflow

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/tensorflow/: There was a 
problem confirming the ssl certificate: EOF occurred in violation of protocol 

(_ssl.c:590) - skipping Could not find a version that satisfies the 
requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for 
tensorflow
```

Easy_install:

```
  easy_install ndg-httpclients
  Searching for ndg-httpclients

  Reading pypi.python.org/simple/ndg-httpclients/
  Download error on pypi.python.org/simple/ndg-httpclients/: EOF 
  occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:661) -- Some packages may not be found!

  Couldn't find index page for 'ndg-httpclients' (maybe misspelled?)
  Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)

  Reading pypi.python.org/simple/
  Download error on pypi.python.org/simple: EOF occurred in 
  violation of protocol (_ssl.c:661) -- Some packages may not be found!
```

Conda (when creating virtual environment and installing a module):

```
 conda create --name hello-world
 Fetching package metadata .......

 CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <None>

 An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
 SSLError(SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",),),)
```

I am not exactly sure what happened. I can still use the already created environments.

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this? Having the exact same problem.

Comment: yes i did it the problem was in my enviromental variable path. Anaconda had issues finding it's directory.